# Calculate average of a time period (from another dataset) per location in r

Tags: r, grouping, mean

I would like to calculate the average burninghours (burningshours$hours_burned) for the time period between ds$date_fixed and ds$date_broken. I know I can calculate this by using the code below:

```
ds$average_burninghours <- sapply (interval(ds$date_fixed, ds$date_broken), function(i)                                
                            mean (burning_hours$hours_burned[burning_hours$date%within%i]))
```

but I would   like to   calculate the burning_hours   depending on the location and position.
   So, I want to add some kind of code looking   lke: 'group_by = c(location, position)', but I cannot manage to do that. Does somebody have ideas about that?

**Sample code:**

```
ds <- data.frame( date_fixed= c("16-3-2015", "19-3-2015", "21-3-2015"), 
                     date_broken = c("18-3-2015", "22-3-2015", "24-3-2015"), 
                     location = c("A", "B", "B"), position = c("1", "2", "2"))

burning_hours <- data.frame(date = c("16-3-2015", "16-3-2015", "17-3-2015", "17-3-2015", 
                          "18-3-2015", "18-3-2015", "19-3-2015", "19-3-2015", "20-3-2015",
                          "20-3-2015", "21-3-2015", "21-3-2015", "22-3-2015", "22-3-2015",
                          "23-3-2015", "23-3-2015", "24-3-2015", "24-3-2015"), 
                           hours_burned= c("10", "11"), location = c("A", "B"), 
                           position = c("1", "2"))
```

**Desired outcome:**

```
     date_fixed date_broken location position avg_burninghours
     16-3-2015  18-3-2015    A         1         10
     19-3-2015  22-3-2015    B         2         11
     21-3-2015  24-3-2015    B         2         11
```

Answer (score 0):

Merge the two data frames and then subset.

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

#Cleaning
ds$date_fixed <- dmy(ds$date_fixed)
ds$date_broken <- dmy(ds$date_broken)
burning_hours$date <- dmy(burning_hours$date)
burning_hours$hours_burned <- as.numeric(as.character(burning_hours$hours_burned))

df <- merge(burning_hours,ds,by = c('location','position'))

df %>%
    group_by(date_fixed,date_broken,location,position) %>%
    filter(date >= date_fixed,date <= date_broken) %>%
    summarise(avg_burninghours = mean(hours_burned))
```

Which gives:

```
  date_fixed date_broken location position avg_burninghours
      (date)      (date)   (fctr)   (fctr)            (dbl)
1 2015-03-16  2015-03-18        A        1               10
2 2015-03-19  2015-03-22        B        2               11
3 2015-03-21  2015-03-24        B        2               11
```

Comment: When I run this code on the whole dataset I have, I only get one outcome for 'avg_burninghours'. It does not make a new column in df. Do you have any idea where this comes from?

Comment: Did you run the cleaning code before the merge and subset? Can you share the `str` of the dataset at the point just before running the merge and subset operation? Improper data-types in your data might be preventing you from manipulating it.